# System.InvalidCastException on line after stepping past line

Tags: c#, datagridview, ienumerable

I receive the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

This error shows up when stepping through, but only after running the line that follows it. (visual studios then points to the prior line for the error).

```
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> CheckedRows = from DataGridViewRow r in dgv_PermitInfo.Rows where Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["Use"].Value) == true select r; //Line that error points to, specifically the Convert.ToBoolean section

if (CheckedRows.Count() > 0) //Line when error triggers
```

Additionally, in another section of my project I have the following lines:

```
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> CheckedRows = from DataGridViewRow r in dgv_VersionInformation.Rows where Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["dgvckbcl_VersionInformation_Use"].Value) == true select r;

if (CheckedRows.Count() > 0)
```

These lines work.

The only difference is, in dgv_VersionInformation, all columns are hard coded, and in dgv_PermitInfo, I create the column "Use" programmatically in the DataTable as follows:

```
DT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Use", typeof(bool)));
```

and then bind DT as the data source. I'm assuming it's the hard coding vs binding that's causing my issue, but I don't know why or how to solve it.

Comment: Linq queries are deferred execution.  So the `Convert.ToBoolean` isn't run until you materialize the query by calling `Count` on it.

Comment: The row count of a DataGridView can be -1 before columns are added during the construction of the form.  I suspect that you need to check for dgv_PermitInfobeing.Rows.Count > 0 and CheckedRow <> null.

Comment: Should it not be: r["Use"].Value (without Cells)?

Comment: @juharr I didn't realize the delayed execution, so that explains why it happens after the fact.

Comment: @mjwills The Use column is a checkbox for the user. In my testing I have run where both grids have only some checked. The dgv_VersionInformation grid doesn't have an issue if I do this, but the dgv_PermitInfo does.

Comment: Try changing the where clause to `r.Cells["Use"].Value != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["Use"].Value)`  Note you don't have to compare a `bool` to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the `Use` DataColumn does not allow nulls by setting [`AllowDBNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false`.

Comment: I had to change it slightly to set the default to false. I'm not populating that column at all when I populate the grid. But your answer pointed me into the right direction. Thank you!